# How can I add multiple domains to Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

My REST API is server multiple domains. How can i allow more than one domain in my headers.

My Code in Java:

```
    public class CORSFilter implements Filter {


        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","abc.com","xyz.com");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, public, max-age=0");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains;");
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)

Comment: Not sure if this is safe. Can you just use a proxy? To rewrite the address.

Comment: @AleksG None of the answers there provide a solution for Spring Boot. I think it should be fine to leave this question open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `CorsRegistry`:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/api/**")
        .allowedOrigins("http://domain1.com","http://domain2.com");
}
```

---

Using `@CrossOrigin`:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://domain1.com","http://domain2.com"})
```

---

Using `application.properties`

```
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=http://domain1.com,http://domain2.com
```